# Facebook Audience Network ads App crashes when Native ad is loading

Tags: java, android, facebook-audience-network

My app was working just fine for many months and all of a sudden users are getting app crashes. Firebase Crashalytics is showing me this error

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
length=16; index=16
com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.3g.B (Unknown Source:6433)
com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.4U.F (Unknown Source:7152)
com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.4U.C (Unknown Source:7129)
com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.4U.<init> (Unknown Source:7095)
com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.4a.<init> (Unknown Source:7249)
com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.55.A (Unknown Source:7964)
com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Ix.<init> (Unknown Source:35176)
com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Ix.B (Unknown Source:35184)
com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Kr.<init> (Unknown Source:38581)
com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.28.<init> (Unknown Source:2905)
com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.2L.<init> (Unknown Source:3231)
com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.KE.g (Unknown Source:37630)
com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.KE.loadAd (Unknown Source:37688)
com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.KE.loadAd (Unknown Source:37685)
com.facebook.ads.NativeAdBase.loadAd (NativeAdBase.java:220)
same.cool.same.retrofit.FragmentMain.loadNativeAd  
(FragmentMain.java:1207)
same.cool.same.retrofit.FragmentMain.onCreateView (FragmentMain.java:227)
```

I am trying to understand the problem but unable to do so. Can anyone suggest why all of a sudden I am getting App Crashes due to facebook native ads?

Thanks

I have put the code in try/catch block as well but still crashing.

Comment: Have you added proguard file some days back and then it started happening? Also can you share the audience network version which you are using? Have you upgraded that?

Comment: No I haven't added proguard file and I am using this 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.+'. I tried to see if there is an update but didn't find any so didn't update. I absolutely did nothing at all.

Comment: Since you are using 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.+', it seems Facebook updated it SDK and while making build it automatically shifted to higher version. I would suggest you to use specific version not 5.+. The latest version is 5.3.1, so try switching to previous one 5.3.0. You can view change logs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/changelog-android#5_3_1). Please let me know whether it worked or not.

Comment: Okay Thanks for your help, but how I am going to ask my users to update the app because they don't always update the app even after prompting.

Comment: And facebook says they changed sdk on 20th may but my app started crashing on 14th June.

Comment: I am checking app on emulator and it's not crashing even on 5.+. Somehow it's crashing only on user's phones. It's not crashing even on my phone.

Comment: For now you can only verify on new users then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194983/discussion-between-prashant-jha-and-abhinav-srivastava).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Facebook team:
The team is still actively working to identify the underlying issue for this case. We will update you as soon as we know more.

You can update latest status of this fatal bug here:
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/415546359031986

Comment: Thanks to their bug, my app is getting uninstalled by leaps and bounds

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem ,it seems that fbsdk's problem, you can change sdk from 5.4 to 5.3 or wait facebook to fix problems